# no such file or directory: 'SwiftyJSON'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, swifty-json

I want to ask why my swiftyJSON.framework in a linked library like disable. I already install that framework before, but suddenly I got that message when I run the project, I already remove and reinstall using pod but when I add that framework to my linked library, its show like disable

here the screenshot;

[image]

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH , I just solved my problem , it caused by Other linker flag in build settings, **i remove all at first and add $(inherited) again** , sorry i got mistake to delete one of framework inside there before. thanks , case closed

Answer (score 1):

Create proper `podfile` where you declare platform and your target (last part of bundle identifier). Make sure they are the same as in your Xcode project settings. When you run `pod install` you will notice that the file .xcworkspace was created. Open it with Xcode and you should be good to go - just remember to `import SwiftyJSON` each time you want to use it.

Here you have a [swiftyJSON documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#integration) for further reading.

Comment: I use .xcworkspace of course . My project is working fine before . And i already used swiftyjson as well for a month ago . But suddenlly, when i want to run my project it was error like that no such file in directory . And the framework is red

Comment: Then i try to delete that framework and i build . And i got same error to another framework . I think this problem is about the path of frameworks is not found . Can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `pod install` with no `SwiftyJSON` in your `podfile`. `SwiftyJSON.framework` should be removed completely from your Xcode, if not, you have to remove it by yourself.

And then add it back to `podfile` and `pod install` again.

Comment: I already reinstall that framework . The framework is downloaded and installed .but when i want to use that, and add to linked library . It show red under framework folder .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delete your Derived Data folder which is location in `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. As well as this, you might want to do a project clean as well as a folder clean like so:

**Project clean:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

**Folder clean:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Make sure your project name isn't the same as the framework name as Xcode doesn't seem to like that and can cause the same error. I hope this helps.

Comment: i already try it but nothing happens , how about my framework search path? there is only 2 items $(inherited) and $(PROJECT_DIR) . is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow there step:

1. Click to framework/project you working on.
2. Remove framework cause error from **framework** folder
3. Move to trash **Pods** folder
4. Go to target
5. Choose Build phase
6. Click x button at trailing of **"[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock"**
7. Clear build folder
8. Clear data in **DerivedData**: File>Workspace setting>Users/admin..DerivedData. Delete data in folder hold this project data
9. Back to terminal and hit **"pod update"**